# mongoDb Index usiing spring Boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

```
@DbCollection(collName = "assets", indexes = {""})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
  @CompoundIndex(def = "{'deleted':1}",name = "deleted_index"),
  @CompoundIndex(def = "{'deleted':1,'_id':1,'modified':1}",name = "deleted_id_modified_index"),
  @CompoundIndex(def = "{'deleted':1,'share':1}",name = "deleted_share_index"),
  @CompoundIndex(def = "{'deleted':1,'_id':1}",name = "deleted_id_index")
})
```

these are not create index in mongoDB